# Scope in AngularJS promise resolution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, restangular

I an using **AngularJS** and **ng-grid** with **RestAngular** to retrieve data.  Since my data is returned in pages, the setup of the grid is more complex and I decided to put it in a directive.  However, when I resolve the promise from **RestAngular**, the result is not bound to `$scope`.

```
    $scope.gridService.get($scope.pagingOptions.currentPage,
                           $scope.pagingOptions.pageSize).then(function(result){
              $scope.gridData = result;
            });
```

As a result `$scope.gridData` is equal to an array inside the promise resolution but nothing outside of it.  Is there a way to bind the result to `$scope`?

I have done so in a `Controller`, but the same pattern is not working here.  I have included the full directive below.

```
angular.module('viz').directive('grid', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            gridCols: '=',
            gridService: '&'
        },
        template: '<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $injector) {
            $scope.gridData = [];
            $scope.gridService = $injector.get($attrs.gridservice);

            $scope.pagingOptions = {
                pageSizes: [5, 10, 20],
                pageSize: 20,
                currentPage: 1
            };

            $scope.gridService.get($scope.pagingOptions.currentPage,
                                   $scope.pagingOptions.pageSize).then(function(result){
              $scope.gridData = result;
            });

            $scope.totalServerItems = $scope.gridData.meta.results;
            $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage = $scope.gridData.meta.page;

            $scope.gridOptions = {
                data: 'gridData',
                selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
                multiSelect: false,
                enableHighlighting: true,
                enableRowSelection: true,
                enablePaging: true,
                showFooter: true,
                pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
                totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
                columnDefs: $scope.gridCols
            };

        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, fn) {

            scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage) {
                    scope.gridData = scope.gridService.get(
                        scope.pagingOptions.currentPage,
                        scope.pagingOptions.pageSize
                    );
                }
            }, true);

        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I needed to move the two variable assignments inside the then function.  I believe this leads the promise to be resolved, but I am not certain of that.

```
$scope.gridService.get($scope.pagingOptions.currentPage,
                       $scope.pagingOptions.pageSize).then(function(result){
     $scope.gridData = result;
     $scope.totalServerItems = $scope.gridData.meta.results;
     $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage = $scope.gridData.meta.page;
});
```